# tesseract-ocr slow inside docker compared to local

Tags: python, docker, tesseract

I've successfully installed `tesseract 5.3.1` inside a docker container built on the base image `FROM:python:3.10` have run a script that takes file_path and runs it through `PyMuPDF` with OCR enabled (using tesseract on the backend).

On my local machine (Windows), I have the same version of tesseract and PyMuPDF installed. Running the exact same code with the exact same file and version of libraries, I get wildly different results - running anything inside Docker on the same machine is much slower than on local.

I tried three configurations:

**Running locally on my machine**

```
100%|██████████| 24/24 [00:49<00:00,  2.06s/it]
It took 0:00:49 to process 24 pages.
```

**Running with the docker install**

```
100%|██████████| 24/24 [03:14<00:00,  8.12s/it]
It took 0:03:14 to process 24 pages.
```

**Running within docker, through bind mount**

```
100%|██████████| 24/24 [02:06<00:00,  5.29s/it]
It took 0:02:06 to process 24 pages.
```

In docker compose, I have the following + I've set the env path for `TESSDATA_PREFIX` to `/code/ocr/tessdata` so it refers to the bind mount.

```
- type: bind
  source: "C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tessdata"
  target: /code/ocr/tessdata
```

The script is essentially this:

```
import fitz # pip install pymupdf
content_dict = {}
pages = fitz.open(pdf_file_path)
for page_num, page in enumerate(pages, start=1):
    list_of_text_in_block = []
    page_data = page.get_textpage_ocr(dpi=400, full=True)
    text_blocks = page_data.extractBLOCKS()
    for text_block in text_blocks:
        block_text = text_block[4]
        list_of_text_in_block.append(block_text)
    content_dict[page_num] = ' '.join(list_of_text_in_block)
```

The command `tesseract --version` yields this inside docker:

```
tesseract 5.3.1
 leptonica-1.79.0
  libgif 5.1.9 : libjpeg 6b (libjpeg-turbo 2.0.6) : libpng 1.6.37 : libtiff 4.2.0 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.4.0     
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found FMA
 Found SSE4.1
 Found OpenMP 201511
 Found libcurl/7.74.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1n zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 libidn2/2.3.0 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.3.0) libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.43.0 librtmp/2.3
```

and this on my local (note: 5.3.1 is the same as 5.3.1.20230401)

```
tesseract v5.3.1.20230401
 leptonica-1.83.1
  libgif 5.2.1 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 2.1.4) : libpng 1.6.39 : libtiff 4.5.0 : zlib 1.2.13 : libwebp 1.3.0 : libopenjp2 2.5.0
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found FMA
 Found SSE4.1
 Found libarchive 3.6.2 zlib/1.2.13 liblzma/5.2.9 bz2lib/1.0.8 liblz4/1.9.4 libzstd/1.5.2
 Found libcurl/8.0.1 Schannel zlib/1.2.13 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.4 libidn2/2.3.4 libpsl/0.21.2 (+libidn2/2.3.3) libssh2/1.10.0
```

Looking at what happens inside docker when the script is running, this is what I get. There are 12 cores available, but only one is being used at 100 %. Even if it was due to resource usage, it does not explain why the bind mount option is 35 % faster than the install within docker, since both are using the same resources.
[image: Image of Docker resource usage]